Data CD's burned with Brasero show up with 8.3 format filenames in Windows
I can't believe no one else seems to have this issue. When I use Brasero to burn a data CD, Windows shows me all the directories and filenames in ancient DOS 8.3 filename format. What am I missing?
$ df -T /dev/sr0
Filesystem     Type    1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sr0       iso9660    624936 624936         0 100% /media/...


A fat32 file-system only allows a 8.3 filename as the primary filename, though using multiple 8.3 entries a longer filename can be encoded into the metadata within the directory.  You didn't specify what file-system you chose (nor what OS/release you used to do the write; thus we cannot even guess at defaults), but if you chose fat32 then 8.3 is default.  Maybe helpful is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928982/what-is-the-difference-between-vfat-and-fat32-file-systems

The simple solution that solved my issue: use Xfburn
Why? Brasero doesn't utilize the ISO 9660 Joliet extension, Xfburn does. Examples using isoinfo command:
# CD burned with Brasero
$ isoinfo -d -i /dev/sr0
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id: LINUX
Volume id: {label name}
Volume set id: 
Publisher id: 
Data preparer id: 
Application id: Brasero-3.12.3
Copyright File id: 
Abstract File id: 
Bibliographic File id: 
Volume set size is: 1
Volume set sequence number is: 1
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 312468
NO Joliet present                      <=====
Rock Ridge signatures version 1 found


# CD burned with Xfburn
$ isoinfo -d -i /dev/sr0
CD-ROM is in ISO 9660 format
System id: 
Volume id: {label name}
Volume set id: {label name}
Publisher id: 
Data preparer id: XFBURN
Application id: XFBURN
Copyright File id: 
Abstract File id: 
Bibliographic File id: 
Volume set size is: 1
Volume set sequence number is: 1
Logical block size is: 2048
Volume size is: 312327
Joliet with UCS level 3 found          <=====
Rock Ridge signatures version 1 found

